# Implications of freezing a saved TensorFlow model

Tags: tensorflow

1. Are there any performance impacts of freezing a saved TensorFlow model ?
2. Is it possible to use a frozen saved TensorFlow model to fine-tune ?

**NOTE :**  By freezing I referred to the content mentioned on [this blog post.](https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "freezing" exactly. It's common to freeze a particular set of layers while training. This usually just means not updating those weights. E.g. a "frozen" model would be a model you're not updating the weights of. Your answers would become trivial then: no, and yes.

Comment: I added the clarification to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Freezing in that blog post just refers to not updating the weights. There is no performance implication.

The Meta file contains the graph definitions, but many workflows don't even use it. It's perfectly legitimate to simply recreate the graph programmatically (I always load my models this way). If you create the graph without an optimizer and loss function that's fine, but it's also fine if you include them. When your ask tensorflow to perform a computation it performs the minimum operations necessary. So if you're doing inference, an optimizer defined in the graph won't be run anyway.

That leads to your second question. It's trivial to perform inference and updates to the same model, it just depends on whether you ask tensorflow to compute the optimizer or not on any particular strep.

There is no such feature in tensorflow as "freezing". That is simply a term being used to describe a workflow. That blog appears dedicated to compacting the model to it's utmost minimum of files. In most cases I doubt that's very critical.